# Cases with square brackets

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, delimiters, cases

How can I subdivide in cases with square brackets?

I mean I want to write:

```
              ⌈ 2_i        if ...
rank (q, l) = | 2_i + 1    if ...
              ⌊ ....
```

with square brackets, not braces.

Comment: I tried to rewrite your question so that it is more easily understood. I hope I understood it correctly. If not, please change it back.

Comment: thanks for the correction, the only thing is that I do not know if the tags are corrent

Comment: Usually $\{$ means "and", and $[$ means "or" --- so it is strange that the option with $[$ is not included in "cases" env.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, I think, this was a common notation in Soviet school of mathematics, but you don't commonly see that in American books.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could patch the `cases` environment, the way Thorsten showed or using the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package and `\patchcmd`. However, it could be better to preserve the original `cases` environment and to define a new one for that purpose. Here is a way, very similar to the original definition, but also using `\lbrack` instead of `\lbrace`, I calles the new environment `sqcases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{sqcases}{%
  \matrix@check\sqcases\env@sqcases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\def\env@sqcases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrack
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
  \rank(q, l) = \begin{sqcases}
      2_i & \text{if \ldots} \\
      2_i+1 & \text{if \ldots} 
    \end{sqcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Though it looks a bit complicated, it's very straightforward: I took the original `cases` definition of amsmath.sty, wrote `sqcases` instead and replaced `\lbrace` by `\lbrack`. I had to use [`\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) because of the `@` symbol in the original `amsmath` commands.

For completeness, heres the way using patching:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}{\lbrace}{\lbrack}
\makeatother
```

After loading `etoolbox`, the respective internal `amsmath` macro is changed to use `\lbrack` instead of `\lbrace`. It's a bit hazardous to patch internal commands, but it's a quick way and may even work after changes in amsmath while our new definition could become different to `cases` then. At least it's good to know such methods.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answers above I would like to present another comprehensible solution to the problem.

```
\begin{align}
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
    x = 1 & a > 0 \\
    x = 2 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right .
\end{align}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. Then, do you have given an answer for the old question where all the answers are right? Can you explain your criticism, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano the accepted answer produces an error because it is using an outdated matrix environment.

Comment: What is the specific error, please?

Comment: @Sebastiano hm, seems to be working now. It was complaining Package amsmath Error: Old form `\matrix' should be \begin{matrix}. \end{align}

Comment: Sorry, but I am not agree with you.

Comment: While this should definitely produce two lines with a square bracket encompassing them on the left, it would be expected that the elements in each cell be left aligned, so the positioning argument should be `{ll}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton indeed, this looks better, thanks

Answer (score 5):

It only requires a slight modification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrack
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[
    \begin{cases}
      0 \\ 1 \\ 2
    \end{cases}
  \]
\end{document}
```

This is the original code from [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) where only `\lbrace` has been replaced by `\lbrack`.

Comment: Are you sure? doing so does not work

Comment: Works fine for me as is.

Comment: @Thorsten: Maybe you could add an explanation so that people who are not well versed with the internals of LaTeX can understand what that does.

Comment: Did you copy the code from Thorsten's example? It works as advertised.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Antony: You have to copy use `amsmath` and then copy the `\makeatoletter ...\makeatother` part to your preamble.

Comment: @Caramdir: I added a short (but hopefully sufficient) explanation.

Answer (score 5):

A Plain "extension" to support such constructs:

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\caseswithdelim#1#2{\left#1\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
  \ialign{\strut$##\hfil$&\quad##\hfil\crcr#2\crcr}}\right.}% you might like it without the \strut
\catcode`@=12
%
\def\bcases#1{\caseswithdelim[{#1}}
\def\vcases#1{\caseswithdelim|{#1}}
%
$$\displaylines{
rank (q,l) = \cases{2_i& if $\ldots$\cr 2_i + 1&if $\ldots$\cr\ldots} \cr
rank (q,l) = \bcases{2_i& if $\ldots$\cr 2_i + 1&if $\ldots$\cr\ldots} \cr
rank (q,l) = \vcases{2_i& if $\ldots$\cr 2_i + 1&if $\ldots$\cr\ldots}
}$$\bye
```

[image: casesext]