# How do I align a system of equations inside square brackets, for different cases?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

[image]

I thought maybe fractions without fraction bar, but seems inconvenient. Also, how would I extend this for more than 2 lines?

Comment: Please add a compilable code that produces the unwanted result, including the packages used.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12157/82917

Comment: I'd suggest editing the title of this question so it is more useful when searched, or just informative to the reader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `\aligned`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\left[\begin{aligned}&x^2+2x-3(x+1)+3=0,&x+1\ge0\\ &x^2+2x-3(-x-1)+3=0,&x+1<0\end{aligned}\right.\Rightarrow
\left[\begin{aligned}&x^2-x=0,&x\ge-1\\ &x^2+5x+6=0,&x<-1\end{aligned}\right.\Rightarrow
\left[\begin{aligned}&x=1,x=0\\&x=-2,x=-3\end{aligned}\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: LaTeX commands are OK, but in book writing avoid such writing. For readability, it is preferably to write step-by-step calculations.. equations placed below each other better, I feel.

Answer (score 2):

The plain TeX's `\eqalign` macro allows only two aligned columns, but OpTeX's `\eqalign` macro is more flexible and it allows arbitrary number of columns, see [Typesetting Math with OpTeX](http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/optex-math.pdf), page 27. So, something like this is working:

```
\def\ralign#1{\left[\eqalign{#1}\right.}
$$
  \ralign{&x^2+2x-3(x+1)+3=0,&x+1\ge0\cr &x^2+2x-3(-x-1)+3=0,&x+1<0} \Rightarrow
  \ralign{&x^2-x=0,&x\ge-1\cr &x^2+5x+6=0,&x<-1} \Rightarrow
  \ralign{&x=1,x=0\cr &x=-2,x=-3}
$$

\bye
```

In pure Plain TeX, you must to define such extended `\eqalign` macro yourself using combination of `\vcenter` and `\halign` primitives.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own environment modelled on `cases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{orcases}
 {%
  \left\lbrack
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}
 }
 {\endarray\right.}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
\begin{orcases}
  x^2+2x-3(x+1)+3=0,  & x+1\ge0 \\
  x^2+2x-3(-x-1)+3=0, & x+1<0
\end{orcases}
& \Rightarrow
\begin{orcases}
  x^2-x=0,    & x\ge-1 \\
  x^2+5x+6=0, & x<-1
\end{orcases}
\\
& \Rightarrow
\begin{orcases}
x=1,  x=0 \\
x=-2, x=-3
\end{orcases}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

I added a wrapping `aligned`, because the whole thing is too long for a single line.

[image]