Can Plain TeX create a branching structure?
I am trying to create a simple branching structure in Plain TeX. I wonder if math has the tools available, I tried many on-line Math TeX tools, but couldn't get any to produce this:
             __ d
            |
            |
     __ b --|
    |       |
    |       |__ e
a --|        __ f
    |       |
    |__ c --|
            |__ g

Basically its just a branching structure, a branches into two items, b and c. And each of those b and c further branch further into two.

I tried many things in math, like use of { but they don't seem to convey the same meaning as "b" is a sub-branch of "a".
It doesn't matter if its vertical or horizontal, but horizontal structure like I give is better, because sometimes a value like "b" might be long, and this horizontal structure is more space-efficient with longer items.

Can this shape/representation of branching sub-items be made in math mode with Plain TeX?

The question is confusing. What does plain TeX have to do with "online math TeX tools"? Are you sure you're using TeX instead of e.g. MathJax or KaTeX (the latter are not on topic here)?

You can use tikz with TeX, see e.g. here https://tikz.dev/tutorial#sec-2.2.2 . There you can create e.g. https://tikz.dev/gd-phylogenetics trees.

you could also do with just rules and boxes, I guess.

I'm also confused by "plain-tex".  I could see this as "just for fun, what's the minimal amount of libraries needed to pull this off", but then that should be made clear.  If it's "I don't want external libraries", then I would ask why (and if it's "because I don't want to install them", then you've probably already installed them).  If "plain-tex" mistakenly means "without an external drawing program", then that's a different question, but OP should clarify that's what happened.  But \input tikz.tex seems to go against the spirit of "plain-tex", under some of those assumptions.

You can try something like this:
\def\crskip{\cr\noalign{\medskip}}
$$
  \delimitershortfall=55pt
  \delimiterfactor=600
  a \cases{b \cases{d \cr e} \crskip c \cases{f\cr g}}
$$

\bye



See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12202/ for a version with square brackets in Plain, which may be closer to what the OP had in mind.

If you set \let\{=[ then you get [ instead { when \cases macro is used.

Here is a way to do it in plain-TeX with Tikz as indicated in my comments. Please note: you need to run LuaTex.

% !!! needs LuaTeX ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

\input tikz.tex
\usetikzlibrary {graphdrawing,graphs}
\usegdlibrary {layered,phylogenetics,trees}

A standard graph:\vskip 1cm

\tikzpicture
  \graph [layered layout,grow'=right] {  % ` reorders sibblings
    a -> {
      b -> {d, e},
      c -> {f,g},
    }
  }
\endtikzpicture

\vskip 1cm
Phylogenetic tree layout:\vskip 3mm

\tikzpicture
  \graph [phylogenetic tree layout,length=2,grow=east] { 
    a -> {
      b -> {d, e},
      c -> {f,g},
    }
  }
\endtikzpicture
\bye


Besides the comments I made here is an other way to do it with Tikz and plain-Tex. As you can see, it gives you much flexibility, e.g. with placement and content.
Some hints:

I used the \matrix {}; command to place a number of nodes
it works much like tables in La/TeX, i.e. separated by & and finished by \\
I named the nodes with (a), ... (g) ((A) .... (G) would work, too)
their text can contain any valid La/TeX syntax, see node (g)
once placed you can connect them the way you want
it's always a good idea to start with straight connections, first, see upper branch
after that it's more obvious how to introduce rectangular paths
finally I put two labels in blue and purple
I could place them absolutely, but here I used a relative position wrt. (d) and (f)
both nodes use anchor=west, which puts the left side at the given coordinate
the purple one uses align=left and \\ inside the text for line breaks
run with pdftex



\input tikz.tex

\tikzpicture
  % ~~~ placing nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \matrix[column sep = 18mm,row sep=8mm]{
        &           & \node (d){D};\\
        & \node(b) {B};\\
        &           & \node(e) {E};\\
   \node(a) {A};\\
        &           & \node(f) {F};\\
        & \node (c) {C};\\
        &           & \node(g) {G: $\sqrt{2}$};\\
  };
  
  % ~~~ connections ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  \draw (a) -- (b); % straight
  \draw (a) -- +(1,0) |- (c);   % with intermediate point
  
  \draw     (b) -- (d);
  \draw     (b) -- (e);
  \draw[red]        (c) -- +(1,0) |- (f);
  \draw[dashed] (c) -- +(1,0) |- (g);
  
  % ~~~ some labels ~~~~~~~~
  \node[anchor=west, xshift=13mm, yshift=-6mm,blue]     at (d) {straight lines used in this branch};
  \node[anchor=west,
       xshift=13mm, yshift=-6mm,
       align=left,purple]   
                    at (f) {rectangular path\\with intermediate point\\used in this branch};
\endtikzpicture
\bye

